# jquery datable add checkbox for object initialised table

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am trying to get a checkbox column added to the jQuery datable, however am unable to do so.

My data table is initialised with a JSON object data and I want to add a column of checkboxes before the data. The data table shows the data but not check box column. The relevant code is as follows

HTML

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Request ID</th>
                <th>Request Date</th>
                <th>Leave Type</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
            console.log(msg);
            $('#mytable').DataTable({
                data: msg,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'RequestID' },
                    { data: 'RequestDate' },
                    { data: 'LeaveType' },
                    { data: 'LeaveStart' },
                    { data: 'LeaveEnd' },
                    { data: 'Status' }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [ {
                  "targets": 0,
                  "searchable": false,
                  "data": null,
                  "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
                }]
            });
```

PHP CODE TO GET DATA FROM MYSQL DATABASE

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$result = $result->num_rows;

if($result->num_rows >0){
   $res = array();
   while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $res[] = $row;
    }
   //$res = array( "data"=>$res);
   $output = json_encode($res);

} else
{
$output = 'fail';
}

echo $output;
die();
```

I have searched through the forums but all of the results i get are for ajax sourced data and not ones populated like I do.

Regards,

Comment: you can get some idea from http://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:
HTML

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name= "check_all" id="check_all" value="1" /></th>
            <th>Request ID</th>
            <th>Request Date</th>
            <th>Leave Type</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

Javascript:

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    data: msg,
    columns: [
        { data: 'RequestID' },
        { data: 'RequestDate' },
        { data: 'LeaveType' },
        { data: 'LeaveStart' },
        { data: 'LeaveEnd' },
        { data: 'Status' }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [ {
         "targets": 0,
          "searchable": false,
          "data": "RequestID",
          "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name= "check_id[]" data-id="'+data+'" />';
           }, 
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. I will now be able to get all the check boxes which are selected with the click event.!!